# Relating an entity to multiple subclass entities as a single relationship to the superclass in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, orm, playframework-2.1, ebean

I'm building an application in Java with the Play 2 framework and ebean ORM.

I have an entity class `Person` that is related to several entity classes with the supertype `Certificate`, which is an `abstract` `@MappedSuperclass`. Currently, I'm creating a relationship for each subclass, like so:

```
public class `Person` extends Model {
    // elided...
    @OneToMany
    public List<SubType1> subType1s;

    @OneToMany
    List<SubType2> subType2s;
    // elided...
}
```

and the subclasses look like this:

```
public class SubTypeGeneric {
    // elided...
    @ManyToOne
    public Person person;
    // elided...
}
```

What I want to know is this: is it possible to group the subclass entities lists in `Person` together into a single superclass list, like so:

```
public class `Person` extends Model {
    // elided...
    @OneToMany
    public List<SuperType> superTypes;
    // elided...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. An association is between entities, not MappedSuperclasses. And if you have a OneToMany can be the inverse association of only one ManyToOne.

If you want that, then Certificate should be annotated with @Entity, and should contain the ManyToOne association with Person instead of all the subclasses.

Comment: I've noticed that when I have a relationship with both a supertype entity and a subtype entity, methods for retrieving the superclass relations return only those, and the subclass relations must be fetched separately. I don't think having `Certificate` as an entity and giving that a relationship with `Person` would allow me to add and retrieve subtypes of `Certificate`.

Comment: I have no experience with EBean, but correct implementations of JPA get all the instances of entities, whether they're instances of subclasses or not, in such a situation. So, either EBean is faulty, or your code is.